# SlickGrid SecondaryHeaderRow synchronous resizing

Tags: jquery, resize, synchronous, slickgrid

Hy,

It's there a way to make the SecondaryHeaderRow synchronous resizing when I resize a column in the HeaderRow ?

Here is the link to it http://li.ro/4bJw

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by that?  SecondaryHeaderRow has no resizing at all - it is a fixed panel below column headers.

Answer (score 0):

SecondaryHeaderRow has no columns - it's just a panel.
What you need is a fixed header row.
Take a look at https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/v2.0a/examples/example-header-row.html